# Manim Display Latex Table

Tags: python, manim

Is there a way to display and animate a latex table using `manim`?

For instance

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{End} &  \\
Top &  & Bottom & Bottom &  \\
 & Top & 40 & 160 & 200 \\
 & Bottom & 640 & 160 & 800 \\
 &  & 200 & 800 & 1000
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How would you go about in `manim`?

```
from manimlib import *
import numpy as np

class TableManim(Scene):
     def construct(self):
     ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it directly with LaTeX it would be like this:

```py
class Table1(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        table = r"""
        \begin{table}[]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}\hline
        &  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{End} &  \\\hline
        Top &  & Bottom & Bottom &  \\
        & Top & 40 & 160 & 200 \\
        & Bottom & 640 & 160 & 800 \\
        &  & 200 & 800 & 1000 \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
        """
        tex_table = TexText(table)
        self.play(Write(tex_table))
```

[image]

But, if you want to make a table with Manim it is a bit more complicated, it would be something like this (you could convert to a function in case you need it)

```py
class Table2(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        table = VGroup(*[
            VGroup(*[
                Text(f"{t}")
                for t in row
            ]).arrange(DOWN,aligned_edge=LEFT)
            for row in [
                ["Top"],
                ["Top","Bottom"],
                ["Bottom",40,640,200],
                ["Bottom",160,160,800],
                [200,800,1000],
            ]],
        )
        table.scale(0.8)
        BUFF = 0.5
        rectangles = VGroup(*[
            Rectangle(
                width=mob.get_width()+BUFF,
                height=max(*[t.get_height() for t in table])+BUFF,
            ).move_to(mob)
            for mob in table
        ])
        for t,r,align_direction in zip(table, rectangles, [UP,None,None,None,DOWN]):
            if align_direction is not None:
                t.align_to(r,align_direction)
                t.shift(-align_direction*BUFF/2)
        table_group = VGroup(*[
            VGroup(t,r)
            for t,r in zip(table,rectangles)
        ])
        table_group.arrange(RIGHT,buff=0)
        self.add(table_group)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I couldn't find a solution anywhere. Btw I love your youtube channel!